# Firefox - Import a Folder of Bookmarks (without erasing existing bookmarks)

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

On the Bookmarks-Bar (in Firefox), I have a folder that contains a hierarchy of bookmarks that I need to give to multiple users who already have their own existing collection of bookmarks.

In Firefox, I know how to backup and restore bookmarks, but (using this method) each time you restore, it erase all existing bookmarks and overwrites them with the ones you've imported.

What's the best way to add a group of bookmarks to someone's existing bookmark collection without doing them one by one. In other words, how can I add a folder of bookmarks to someone's existing bookmarks-collection efficiently?

Comment: I haven't tried this in recent times, but how about exporting each set of bookmarks as html. Then combine them with a text editor and import back into Firefox.